# SSIS tasks go green very quickly and do nothing

Tags: ssis

SISS 2008 - My package goes green very quickly, but does nothing.
The connections are opened, but nothing is being passed in the connection.

This problem started when I moved from a test environment to a production one. I'm using package configurations to hold the connection data.

Comment: Could you give a little more info? Sounds like your connection strings are valid (or else the package would fail) but no data is in the production tables that you are extracting from.

Comment: What info do you require? If I create a new package and add exactly the same tasks, replicate everything exactly. It works. (this won't work if I delete the task and recreate in the package that doesn't work)
By nothing I mean there is no query string being passed. There should be.

It's as if theres a setting that says, just verify I don't have any logical errors but don't bother to do anything with the data.

Comment: Use SQL Profiler to see if queries are fired against the right DB or not.

Comment: I have, thats why I know their not being ran. I'm running them against a postgres database, so I'm checking pg_stat_activity instead

Comment: The connection is opened to the correct database, but there is no query string in it.

Comment: So, when you created a new package from scratch with exactly the same tasks it works? Hmm, I would say check the package properties. Maybe something was changed in the default package properties-specifically the execution properties.

Comment: Yeah, I did that, nothing looks different. The only thing that I can see that's different is the query string is empty when I look at what's running on the server.

Comment: The only thing I can put it down to is that I was using a data source. which apparently isn't a good idea, so I'm using config files now and hope that it won't happen again. looks like I have a lot of work to do...

Comment: Yeah, I guess I would have to see your pkg to really pin point what is going on. Good Luck!

Comment: Pleas add more info. Compare your newly created package using a tool and not manually. You can even use things such as Notepad++ to find out the differences.

Comment: There are some differences, but nothing that would suggest why I'm having this problem. Marc, you deleted a different problem, please read the questions before deletion. THIS IS NOT THE SAME PROBLEM! This problem went away when I stopped using data sources. So the problem is that SSIS STALLS (STAYS YELLOW) ON DATA FLOW TASK. Google searchs point to a provider problem.

Comment: I don't know if it is the provider, its strange that it's only on one table. I wish someone hadn't deleted the real question so I can point you in that direction for more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wrong - I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the data, as I removed all but one row. Some exception must be occuring that isn't handled by the provider which is why we're getting the strange behaviour.

Comment: This has something to do with the way postgres handles varchar columns with '' (two single quotes) in it. When you select, they become null, which means you can't insert into a column with NOT NULL. I think the provider didn't handle this exception.

Comment: Not really sure whats going on, provider is investigating

Answer (score 0):

I put this down to using data sources and not package configurations.